# Having trouble installing protobuf on python mac

Tags: python, macos, protocol-buffers

After running easy_install protobuf I'm getting this:

```
Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/protobuf-2.5.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for protobuf
Finished processing dependencies for protobuf
```

Which (I guess) means that it thinks it's OK but when I try to import google.protobuf I get an error.

```
Eyals-MacBook-Pro:python2.7 eredler$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

I would appreciate any assistance regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: Try dropping the `google.`, i.e. `import protobuf`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your python installation? For me, it does work, same in/output in the first 3 lines you quoted.